# Purpose of FROM command - Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Main purpose** of Docker container is to avoid carrying guest OS in every container, as shown below.

[image]
As mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from),  The `FROM` instruction initializes a new build stage and sets the Base Image for subsequent instructions. As such, **a valid Dockerfile must start** with a `FROM` instruction.

My understanding is, `FROM <image>` allow a container to run on its own OS.

---

Why a valid Docker file must have `FROM` instruction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Containers don't run a full OS, they share the kernel of the host OS (typically, the Linux kernel). That's the "Host Operating System" box in your right image.

They do provide what's called "user space isolation" though - roughly speaking, this means that every container manages its own copy of the part of the OS which runs in user mode- typically, that's a Linux distribution such as Ubuntu. In your right image, that would be contained in the "Bins/Libs" box.

You can leave out the `FROM` line in your Dockerfile, or use `FROM scratch`, to create a blank [base image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages), then add all the user mode pieces on top of a blank kernel yourself.

Comment: Assume Windows as host OS, if I launch container by saying `FROM ubuntu` in Dockerfile, then these C executables(say  `/bin/ls`, `/bin/grep`)  in this container are mainly linux based binaries(ELF-64). How these binaries(ELF-64) work with windows host OS(COFF format binaries)? with docker daemon in the middle

Comment: If you're running Docker for Windows in Linux container mode, it'll basically run a Linux VM behind the scenes. All your containers share the Linux kernel of that VM (not the Windows kernel).

Comment: Actually, looks like that's no longer accurate: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DockerAndLinuxContainersOnWindowsWithOrWithoutHyperVVirtualMachines.aspx - not quite sure how exactly native Linux Container support on Windows works, it *might* be somewhat similar to Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Another common use of `FROM` is to chain builds together to form a multi-stage build of smaller images.

This would be useful for instance to limit redundant rebuilding during failed auto-builds.

Comment: A link or some more information would be great. If someone doesn't know how to use `FROM`, they probably also doesn't know what `multi-stage builds` are.

Comment: Here's a link to more info on multi-stage builds: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/

Answer (score 1):

FROM instruction specifies the underlying OS architecture that you are gonna use to build the image. You have to use some form of base image for you to get started with building an image. It can be ubuntu, centos or any minimal linux image like ALPINE which is only 5MB!. The idea is to install only the packages you need rather than having everything bundled and packaged as a distribution. This makes the size of the docker images very small as compared to the full blown OS distribution. I hope this answers your question. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: "The idea is to install only the packages you need rather than having everything bundled and packaged as a distribution." What exactly are you bundling? If a container has its own kernel, then why would I use docker container?

Comment: "If a container has its own kernel" - it doesn't. The kernel is shared with the host OS.

Comment: Yes same as what @Max said above. Here Docker daemon manages your kernel and how it utilises the resources available to it .